# Why is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} = -\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Res}\Bigl( \frac{\pi \cot \pi z}{z^4} \; ; \; 0 \Bigr) = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

The text I'm reading that states $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}= -\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Res}\Bigl( \frac{\pi \cot \pi z}{z^4} \; ; \; 0 \Bigr) = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$, without explanation. Where does the $-\frac{1}{2}$ come from? I thought the first equality should be $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}= - \operatorname{Res}\Bigl( \frac{\pi \cot \pi z}{z^4} \; ; \; 0 \Bigr)$.

Comment: The poles are at $\pm n$ but the sum is only on positive $n$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the integral
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{C_N} \frac{\pi \cot \pi z}{z^4} dz
\end{eqnarray*}
where the the contour is a circle with center zero and radius $N$, now consider the limit as $N$ tends to infinity.